# How to access RDDs that are supposed to be cached from the DAGScheduler?

Tags: caching, apache-spark, scheduler, rdd, directed-acyclic-graphs

Does anyone know how can I extract the RDDs that are supposed to be cached from the DAGScheduler. Not the ones that are really cached but the ones that are intended to be cached before the execution of stages starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SparkContext.getPersistentRDDs`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@getPersistentRDDs:scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]]):

```
spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs: Map[Int, RDD[_]]
```

> Returns an immutable map of RDDs that have marked themselves as persistent via cache() call.

Answer (score 0):

### DAGScheduler

`DAGScheduler` does not participate in caching RDDs (and very little in task execution).

`DAGScheduler` is a "function" that accepts RDD lineages (hence the prefix `DAG` for DAG of RDD dependencies) and produces DAG of stages with tasks (as `TaskSets`) and only with the tasks for partitions that are missing (i.e. BlockManagers have no RDD blocks for them).

With that said, I'd immediately mark your question about accessing cached RDD from DAGScheduler as invalid.

### getPersistentRDDs

You could use `SparkContext.getPersistentRDDs` (as [@user6910411](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42376630/1305344) pointed out), but it gives you RDDs that **requested** to be cached/persisted (but either have not yet or will never be).

`cache` and `persist` methods are lazy so it's only when you execute an action when the RDD blocks get stored in BlockManagers on executors (and hence accessible without reading the data again from the source).

Persisting RDD could also fail (e.g. low memory) yet the internal registry could still reference the RDDs as cached.

---

*(still looking into use cases when cache/persist would fail)*

Comment: What I am looking for actually is the extraction of RDDs that are supposed to be cached and in which stage this cache will be executed (after an action is fired). I think with SparkContext.getPersistentRDDs , the map is filled before the DAG is constructed. So I think in order to get this information about cache()<-->stageId we need to access it from the DAGScheduler.

Comment: Ah, that's what SparkListener is for. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener. Register for SparkListenerBlockUpdated and see what you can get from it. Don't expect anything from DAGScheduler in this regard.